# Applicability in SNMP scalar objects

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, scalar

What is the correct way to show applicability of SNMP Scalar Objects when doing an SNMP-GET request?

For example, imagine that we have a monitoring parameter that is only valid under certain system configuration:

- Should we return a noSuchObject error, and act like the object is temporarily not implemented?
- Should we return a noSuchInstance error?
- Should we provide an 'not-applicable value', that is returned in this cases?
- Should we return the DEFVAL?
- Any other option?

Is there a clear explanation for this in the RFC's ?

Answer (score 0):

Think this should be handled by your MIB design not SNMP protocol usage.

1) Look at SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact which seems a reasonable approach for DisplayStrings.

"The textual identification of the contact person for this managed node, together with information on how to contact this person.  **If no contact information is known, the value is the zero-length string.**"

2) For [Counters or guages](http://vegan.net/MRTG/countergauge.php) in scalars  there will be a value always else you would be using a SNMP table presumably.

I know this question is old !